# C# - Get specific text from output

Tags: c#, listbox, split, minecraft

I have a server wrapper, it basically takes the output from a console and provides extra features for minecraft.

There is a player list on the side, i want the list to show connected players.

```
Here is the output for a player Joining:
2012-05-17 17:56:32 [INFO] name [/192.168.0.16:50719] logged in with entity id 1873 at ([world] -34.8881557254211, 63.0, 271.69999998807907)

Output for player leaving:
2012-05-17 17:58:03 [INFO] name lost connection: disconnect.quitting
```

How can i add the player to the list when joining, and remove when quitting?

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Ive tried spliting the text, but i haven't dont much work with strings in the past. It just failed!

Comment: Why is there an IP with port where the playername is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit hacky, but this should work:

```
var input = "2012-05-17 17:56:32 [INFO] name [/192.168.0.16:50719] logged in with entity id 1873 at ([world] -34.8881557254211, 63.0, 271.69999998807907)";

var name = Regex.Matches(input, @"\]\s(.+?)\s")[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Can people have spaces in their names?

Comment: No, just single word usernames

Answer (score 0):

More of a partial answer:

Assuming you are just parsing the console output and responding to messages accordingly - can you not just parse the string to see if it contains a certain phrase e.g. "logged in" and "disconnect"? You can use regular expressions to get the required tokens from the string to build up an object from the messages. I assume 'name' is the players name - you may not even need to use regex in this case - can players have duplicate names on a minecraft server?

If not then you should be able to use this token as a key for a dictionary e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, playerObject>
```

That way you can associate the messages with an object in the list e.g.

Pseudocode:

```
private void OnNewMessage(string message) 
{
   if(message.Contains("logged in")) 
   {
      // Build player object
      // some code here ... to parse the string

      // Add to player dictionary
      PlayerDict.Add(playerName, newPlayerObject);
   }
   else if(message.Contains("disconnect")) 
   {
      // Find the player object by parsing the string
      PlayerDict.Remove(playerName);
   }
}
```

Can you give a bit more info on what you've got so far and what tech you are writing this in? There are a few more considerations (since you have listbox in tags I assume it's winforms) such as binding and depending on the tech used the method can differ slightly

Comment: Thanks for the help, im not too sure how to use this though, i haven't really done a lot of this. Im a bit of a noob to C# ive been using VB.NET for years.

Comment: They are one and the same as far as I'm concerned :) just different syntax is about 98% of the differences! Do you want to post your 'receive message' code so far? Also - use Dave Bishs regex that hes posted - use Regex class (System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace) and pass the string as the input, this should return the name of the user

Comment: Yeah, im only 15, i haven't learnt everything yet, but i have noticed the similar syntax, its just the .NET framework really

Comment: Ah you'll learn something new every day - I'm sure I'd been using it for about a year until I realised that System.IO.Path could help combine paths/filenames without messing about with slashes etc :)

Comment: Just like you said, you learn something everyday - ive just learnt System.IO.Path - ive been using \\ all the time. Facepalm.

Comment: Haha, miscellaneous tip time - did you know you can quickly navigate over words when editing text by holding CTRL? Try typing a sentence and then holding control and going backwards with the left cursor key. Useful when editing code or typing SQL queries. There are also secret right click menus in Win7 (not sure about XP) if you right click on a file/folder using SHIFT you get more options (like open in cmd prompt option) :)

Comment: Yeah, i know the SHIFT function i used it for a C++ thing i did, with the command prompt. Nice tips thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off storing your players in a Dictionary (map) and then you can add and remove them by name.

To capture the name you could use a regex or it looks like you could probably take the substring starting at the position of the name since that appears consistent.

`string name = outputString.Substring(27)`

Then you could split on a space and take the result at position 0.

`name = name.Split(' ')[0];`

Comment: Combine this with Charleh's answer and pretty much have all the code you need.

Comment: Yeah assuming the message format doesn't change this should work fine - saving the need for any regex.